# Javascript destructuring new constructed object when calling a function

Tags: javascript, destructuring

```js
const {message, stack} = new Error('NOT GOOD');

logger.error({message, stack});  // <--- calling winston logger
```

I am wondering if above code can be shorten it into single line, something like:

```
logger.error({message, stack} = new Error('NOT GOOD'));
```

###### UPDATE: the reason why I got this question:

This is how I format the winston log (in typescript):

```js
// Creating file log message format
const logFormat = printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
    return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${stack || message}`;
});
```

When I call:

```js
logger.error(new Error('NOT GOOD'));
```

The output is as such:

```
2022-01-28 12:12:12 error: undefined
```

But if I:

```js
const {message, stack} = new Error('NOT GOOD');

logger.error({message, stack});  // <--- calling winston logger
```

It work as intended. Display error `message` and `stack`.

Comment: Sadly not. The second statement is assigning the Error to the return value of `logger.error`. You should see the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call`.

Comment: Why don't you pass the `Error` directly? _"The `info` parameter provided to a given format represents a single log message. The object itself is mutable. Every `info` must have at least the `level` and `message` properties:"_  ([Source](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#streams-objectmode-and-info-objects)) - There's no restriction on what object you pass to `.error()`/`.log()`. It just has to have `level` and `message` properties

Comment: Destructuring and Deconstruction are two different concepts.

Comment: @Andreas But the resulting log is always `undefined`, hence I had to destructured the `Error` object before passing as and argument to `logger.error()` function.

Comment: I am using typescript, don't know if that is related?